# Socket.io message/comment send twice. How to resolve this?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, socket.io, vuex, message

I put first my emit to join in a room and used the id of board

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.on('joinboard', function (data) {
      socket.join(data.boardId)
    })
```

Here is my emit of the joinboard client.

```
created () {
          this.socket.emit('joinboard', {
            boardId: this.$route.params.boardId
          })
        }
```

This is the reply socket emit in server.

```
socket.on('reply', function (data) {
      io.sockets.in(data.boardId).emit('reply', data)
    })
```

and here is my mounted on reply if emitted.

```
mounted () {
    this.socket.on('reply', data => {
      this.$store.commit('legalAdvice/SET_MESSAGE_REALTIME', data)
    })
  }
```

Here is my code for reply emitted

```
this.socket.emit('reply', {
            userId: this.user,
            boardId: this.boardId,
            message: this.message,
            createdAt: new Date(),
            lawyerReply: !this.$store.getters['legalAdvice/legalAdvice'].lawyerReply,
            isAdvice: this.$store.getters['user/user'].user.isLawyer,
            user: {
              fullName: this.$store.getters['user/user'].user.fullName,
              imageUrl: this.$store.getters['user/user'].user.imageUrl
            }
          })
```

This is my vuex from the `mounted()` code below

```
SET_MESSAGE_REALTIME (state, payload) {
    state.legalAdvice.conversations.push(payload)
    if (!payload.isAdvice) {
      state.legalAdvice.followUps = state.legalAdvice.followUps - 1
    }
    state.legalAdvice.lawyerReply = payload.lawyerReply
  }
```

The problem here is. The message sent twice sometimes 3 but if I refresh it before i sent a comment. There is no bug. is there any problem with my code here? How can I resolve this?

Comment: Usually duplicates like this are because you have installed duplicate event handlers so the message is sent once, but you have multiple event handlers for the same event so you process it multiple times.  There's nothing here in the code you show that could show us one way or another whether that's happening because we'd need to see a much larger context.  But, that's something to examine your code for.  For example, if you call `mounted()` more than once, that would cause this.

Comment: @jfriend00 here is my updated code sir. that is all ive used also if I will not refresh the page, it will sent also to other boards :( I do not know why. but if I refreshed it before I message or comment. all is smooth.

Comment: I'd suggest you add this `console.log(this.socket.id, ": mounted")` to the start of the `mounted()` function and see if it gets called more than once for a given `socket.id`.

Comment: it says this sir `undefined ": mounted"`. once only

Comment: Still stumped.  I'd have to see a lot more of the code to have any more ideas.  Which exact piece of code executes twice or more?

Comment: sir, i am not good at sockets yet. The problem is, the first user accessed the board then the `undefined ": mounted"` showed then the 2nd user accesed the board then this one `undefined ": mounted"` counted 2 after that the one who last accessed the board the one executes the comment twice

Comment: That sounds like it means you're calling `mounted()` each time a user accesses the board.  Can you show ALL the code that can ever call `mounted()`?

Comment: can you suggest any other process? I want to have a real time on commenting in a board which has 2 user a client and lawyer. i did not use socketid, i used the only the boardId and store it in a room. is there any other better way sir?

Comment: `mounted () {
    console.log(this.socket.id, ": mounted"),
    this.socket.on('reply', data => {
      this.$store.commit('legalAdvice/SET_MESSAGE_REALTIME', data)
    })
  }` this is all my mounted code

Comment: I asked to see the code where you CALL mounted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209827/discussion-between-peter-parker-and-jfriend00).

Comment: I updated my question. last part is my code where i called mounted

Comment: I'm going to sleep now, but I still don't see anywhere that you call `mounted()`.  Never mind, I guess it's called automatically by vuejs.  I don't know that framework so I will probably have to leave this for someone else.  I'm pretty sure it's getting called too many times or you need to find a different/better place to put the `this.socket.on('reply'....)` code.

Comment: @jfriend00 i have new question about sockets. i cannot receive any data from client side.  here is the link to my question and details. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60808240/how-to-fix-this-client-side-socket-on-not-receiving-data-vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60808240/how-to-fix-this-client-side-socket-on-not-receiving-data-vue)

Comment: I don't know Vue so hopefully someone who does can help you there.